# Reading file from a remote HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, remote-access, readfile

I am trying to read a file from a remote HDFS system and display in the console of my local machine.  Please note that the local machine can establish connection to any of the HDFS nodes only by the SSH key which is in the form of .pem file.

When I execute the below shown piece of code, the program runs, remains idle for some time and finally displays:

```
BlockMissingException : Could not obtain block
```

My code:

```
try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("remoteUser");

            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
                public Void run() throws Exception {
                    conf = new Configuration();
                    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
                    conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
                    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
                    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
                    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml"));
                    conf.set("fs.default.name", hdfsurl);
                    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsurl);
                    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "remoteUser");
                    conf.set("hadoop.ssl.enabled", "false");
                    readFromHDFS(hdfsurl);
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {



public static void readFromHDFS(String hdfsURL) throws Exception {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path path = new Path(hdfsURL);
        if (!fileSystem.exists(path)) {
            System.out.println("File does not exists");
            return;
        }
        FSDataInputStream in = fileSystem.open(path);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("line read from hdfs...." + sc.nextLine());
        }
        in.close();
        fileSystem.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) 
type    `hadoop fsck HDFS_FILE`
check if the particular hdfs file is healthy
If not, then the particular file is corrupted. remove corrupted file and try below command

2) type `hadoop dfsadmin -report`
check if the value of `Missing blocks: 0`

Comment: Good. I feel one should try to use Hadoop Admin commands for debugging such issues

Comment: Thank you Nirmal Ram.  But I checked, the status of the file is HEALTH only.